# java ignores proxy in command line argument

Tags: java, maven, proxy

I am trying to build some .jar package with maven. Since I am connected to the Internet thru proxy server, my command looks like this:

```
mvn -DargLine="-Dhttp.proxyHost=my.proxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080" install
```

so that all other processes created by this will use those settings.

However,  during the TESTS phase fork process tries to download some packages and even though it **has** proxy settings in its arguments (`ps ax | grep java` shows that), I can see with `netstat -ntp` that this process is connecting directly to the repository ignoring the proxy settings.

`tcpdump` shows no connections to 8080.

Any ideas?

**UPD:**

So, basically I am trying to build JBoss. As far as I understand it consists of different subsystems which should be build separately. For example, I want to build jboss-as-cmp. My commands without DargLine:

```
cd /root/jboss/jboss-eap-6.1.0.Alpha/jboss-eap-6.1-src/cmp
mvn install
```

to my mvn settings.xml in /root/.m2 I added

```
<proxies>
   <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>my.proxy.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
   </proxy>
</proxies>
```

Ive read, that surefire plugin can be configuried to use proxy as well, so in my pom.xml for jboss-as-cmp I added

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
           <includes>
                <include>org/jboss/as/cmp/**/*TestCase.java</include>
            </includes>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                   <http.proxyHost>my.proxy.com</http.proxyHost>
                   <http.proxyPort>8080</http.proxyPort>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

My mvn version

```
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (rNON-CANONICAL_2013-04-24_16-52_root; 2013-04-24 16:52:00+0300)
Maven home: /usr/share/apache-maven-3.0.5
Java version: 1.7.0_19, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.19.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.8.6-203.fc18.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Environment variables:

```
M2_HOME=/usr/share/apache-maven-3.0.5
PATH=/usr/share/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

I have not changed any other settings in pom.xml for jboss-as-cmp.

Answer (score 2):

Typically to use proxies you should be defining them in your settings.xml found in user-home-dir/.m2/settings.xml

Example is:

```
<settings>
  <proxies>
   <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.somewhere.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.somewhere.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
  </settings>
```

See http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: i tried also this way, proxy settings are used by the parent process and mvn downloads some dependences, but when TESTS phase starts downloading ends up with "connection timeout", which is logical -netstat shows direct connection to repository.

Comment: You should attach your POM or a section of your POM where your test and test scoped dependencies are setup so we can get a clearer picture.   Also have you tried removing the -DargLine and just declaring the proxy info direct (outside of the quotes and defined like your doing argLine)